# Ordering the cells by the expression of specific genes

Tags: r, scrnaseq, ggplot2

I have 209 cells. I want to show the expression of two genes by ordering my cells. Imagine something like a plot on which y axis shows the read counts range from 0 to 10000 and x axis shows the number of cells (there is a link of an example picture that I wish to produce the same). So that two colours bars each colour for a gene.

I have used this code but result is not as I want at all

```
# Library
 library(tidyverse)

 # Create data
 value1=abs(rnorm(26))*2
 data=data.frame(x=LETTERS[1:26], value1=value1, value2=value1+1+rnorm(26, sd=1) )

 # Reorder data using average?
 data = data %>% rowwise() %>% mutate( mymean = mean(c(value1,value2) )) %>% arrange(mymean) %>% mutate(x=factor(x, x))

 # plot
 ggplot(data) +
   geom_segment( aes(x=x, xend=x, y=value1, yend=value2), color="grey") +
   geom_point( aes(x=x, y=value1), color=rgb(0.2,0.7,0.1,0.5), size=3 ) +
   geom_point( aes(x=x, y=value2), color=rgb(0.7,0.2,0.1,0.5), size=3 ) +
   coord_flip()
```

This is link of my data and my result picture

[image]

And to some [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PPFjULGV4CfJvRbubtn6kb5f5qYlpJ5W/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Could you add an example of what a lollipop is? (a link or something like that?) And what have you tried to make that plot (To avoid suggesting to do the same and help you more specifically)

Comment: Thank you, I edited my post. Actually lollipop plot itself dose not matter that can be replaced by any other plots. The problem is that I could not figure out how to plot the same as picture and what I have tried up to now did not answer my question :(

Comment: could you further explain how this picture doesn't help you ?. I am still trying to figure out how I can help

Comment: Thank you, because on gene seems to be compressed at the end  and does not allow to another gene to be cleared. I don't know how to have another gene on another axis or showing y axis in log10

Comment: So, your problem is how to convert an axis to log10? This is answered in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699493/transform-only-one-axis-to-log10-scale-with-ggplot2) and other venues. In ggplot2 you can't have two axis by design: it is against the grammar of graphics.